# ClickAwayListener doesn't fire when clicking on a link/button to navigate to other route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, use-effect

I'm using Material-UI ClickAwayListener component with the existing code that used react-router. The button is outside of the `<ClickAwayListener> ... </ClickAwayListener>` and so I expected the `onClickAway` to fire before navigating to other route. But it didn't

Below are the replicate of my code, to some extent to demonstrate what I mean

```js
function Component(){

  const handleClickAway = () => {
    // Do something here
  }

  return (
  <>
    <button>
      <Link to="/other-route">Click here </Link>
    </button>
    // Some other element here
    <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={handleClickAway}>
      <div>
        // Content
      </div>
    </ClickAwayListener>
  </>
  )
}
```

So if I click any where that is outside of `<ClickAwayListener>` and `<button>` the `handleClickAway` fired, but if I click onto the `<button>` which contains the like to other route it doesn't.

I tried to look onto source code of `ClickAwayListener` and this [part](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/4fa3f7bc30da1c86bb5702df06dbcff61c538e4b/packages/material-ui/src/ClickAwayListener/ClickAwayListener.js#L128), I believe, is responsible for detecting the click

```js
 React.useEffect(() => {
    if (mouseEvent !== false) {
      const mappedMouseEvent = mapEventPropToEvent(mouseEvent);
      const doc = ownerDocument(nodeRef.current);

      doc.addEventListener(mappedMouseEvent, handleClickAway);

      return () => {
        doc.removeEventListener(mappedMouseEvent, handleClickAway);
      };
    }

    return undefined;
  }, [handleClickAway, mouseEvent]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

As far as I can understand, this part will, first add an event listener to click event when the component mount/re-render and will remove that listener before the component unmount (default behavior for `useEffect()`). But if this is the case, then before the component get unmount by any event that involved clicking outside of the area of `ClickAwayListener`, the `onClickAway` listener should be fired because the listener still attach to the click event.

So in short this is the behavior I expect:

Button click --> `onClickAway` fire --> component get unmount --> go to new route --> clean-up code of useEffect() run --> the listener get removed

But this is what happen so far

Button click --> component get umount --> go to new route --> clean-up code of useEffect() run --> the listener get removed

Can someone help explain to me why this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ClickAwayListener` component works by attaching the event listener to the [`document`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/4fa3f7bc30da1c86bb5702df06dbcff61c538e4b/packages/material-ui/src/ClickAwayListener/ClickAwayListener.js#L57), when a mouse event fires, it fires `onClickAway` only when the mouse event is not inside the element.

The [`Link`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/modules/Link.js) component from `react-router-dom` essentially renders something like this:

```js
<a onClick={() => navigate()}>click</a>
```

When you click the link and call `navigate()`, React unmounts the current component and mounts the next page component in the next frame. But the thing is, `document` handlers are only processed **after the next re-render**, at that point, the event handler from the `ClickAwayListener` had already been removed since it was unmounted, so nothing get called.

The problem can be solved by waiting until after the next re-render when the handlers from `document` have been called.

```js
<button
  onClick={() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      history.push("/2");
    });
  }}
>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 64531264/clickawaylistener-doesnt-fire-when-clicking-on-a-link-button-to-navigate-to-oth]

Comment: why document handlers are only processed after the next re-render? I thought it should be process before the navigation since it's native event handler.

Answer (score 9):

In the [issue](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/17402) that Tejogol linked, [a commenter](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/17402#issuecomment-1013342932) recommended use of these props on the `ClickAwayListener` component, as it allows the component to catch the touch event at its start, before the link does.

```
<ClickAwayListener mouseEvent="onMouseDown" touchEvent="onTouchStart">
```

I was having the same issue as you, and this worked for me! It was also the least intrusive, as I didn't want to mess with my `react-router-dom` code.

Answer (score 1):

An [issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/17402) related to your question was opened in September 2019 in the [Material UI repository](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui) where the Clickawaylistener doesn't fire for both buttons and links. However as recently as May 2020, the issue does not appear to have been adequately addressed. I recommend opening a new issue in the repository to confirm that this isn't a bug as it relates to buttons.

As a potential workaround in the meantime, and depending on your use case, you could either use a `<Link>` or `<Button>` component with an `onClick` prop:

```
import React from "react";
import ClickAwayListener from "@material-ui/core/ClickAwayListener";
import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

export default function Home() {
  let history = useHistory();

  const handleClickAway = () => {
    console.log("Clicked Away");
  };

  function handleClick() {
    handleClickAway();
    history.push("/about");
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Link to="/about" onClick={handleClickAway}>
        Link
      </Link>
      <Button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
        Button
      </Button>
      <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={handleClickAway}>
        <div>Home Page</div>
      </ClickAwayListener>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I've also included a working example on Codesandbox.

[image: Working Example]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by using this function instead of the material-ui ClickAwayListener: https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/src/useClickAway.ts

```
import { RefObject, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { off, on } from './util';

const defaultEvents = ['mousedown', 'touchstart'];

const useClickAway = <E extends Event = Event>(
  ref: RefObject<HTMLElement | null>,
  onClickAway: (event: E) => void,
  events: string[] = defaultEvents
) => {
  const savedCallback = useRef(onClickAway);
  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = onClickAway;
  }, [onClickAway]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = (event) => {
      const { current: el } = ref;
      el && !el.contains(event.target) && savedCallback.current(event);
    };
    for (const eventName of events) {
      on(document, eventName, handler);
    }
    return () => {
      for (const eventName of events) {
        off(document, eventName, handler);
      }
    };
  }, [events, ref]);
};

export default useClickAway;
```

I didn't want to import the library as a dependency so I created a hook out of this code and copied the util functions into it

```
const on = (obj: any, ...args: any[]) => obj.addEventListener(...args);
const off = (obj: any, ...args: any[]) => obj.removeEventListener(...args);
```

An example of the hook in use is provided here: https://streamich.github.io/react-use/?path=/story/ui-useclickaway--demo

Comment: this did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers here offer solutions, but none went into detail about why this happened. So this is what I think is happening

At the time I posted this question, I was using React 17. For any React version below 18, there is one "bug" that appears when using `addEventListener` or any async action like `async/await` or `Promise`. This is discussed in [GitHub React 18 discussion](https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/21)

You can try out this code in React version below 18 and you should observe similar result

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Test in useEffect " + count);
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Another one useEffect");
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const button = document.getElementById("buttonId");
    button.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
    return () => {
      button.removeEventListener("click", handleClick);
    };
  }, []);

  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log("First print Count is " + count);

    setCount(count + 1);
    setCount(count + 100);
    console.log("Second print Count is " + count);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>Count is: {count} </div>
      <button id="buttonId">Click</button>
    </>
  );
}
```